MUI data-grid-premium customize drop rules
I am using MUI data-grid-premium and I currently have a drag&drop/rowReordering data-grid as documented here https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-ordering/.
Passing that prop allows me to have draggable and droppable rows on that data-grid and that is exactly what I want.
On top of that I just need to implement the following rule: I can drag and drop "freely" in the data-grid but I can't drop a row on the first position/on top of the first row that I have on the data-grid.
I have been trying to do that with the events/callbacks described here https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-ordering/ (rowDragOver, rowDragEnd, onRowOrderChange, ...), but I'm not being able to find an easy way to do this..
Is there a way to customize the data-grid with that custom rule?
Thanks in advance, best regards,
Hugo.
